# Can’t Heimdall see all the Infinity Stones? (And other concerns.)

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel, infinity-stones

Throughout phase one and phase two, at various points of various movies we are given a little information about three different Infinity Stones — the blue stone (Tesseract) in Captain America, Iron Man and others; the purple/violet stone in Guardians of Galaxy; and the red stone (the Aether) in Thor: The Dark World.

What I want to know is:

- Who is the all-father who supposedly created the six Infinity Stones?
- Where are the rest of the Infinity Stones?
- What happens to the owner of the stones (although a brief example is shown about individual stones in different movies)
- Can't Heimdall see the position of all Infinity Stones, and hence alert the warriors when someone is about to mess around with any of them?

Comment: You seem to be trying to ask a bunch of different questions (at least three by my count). Might I suggest you edit down to *just the key point* you're trying to understand.

Comment: I completely agree with @Richard: I actually like the questions, but there are a bunch of different questions haphazardly thrown out, which makes it harder to separate what you really want. You may want to trim the fat, so to speak.

Answer (score 3):

The Infinity stones in the movie are different than those of the comics. The All-Father/Odin, did not create them. The Collector says the stones were 6 separate singularities formed before the creation of the universe. I don't know what Singularity means in this instance, but in natural science, gravitational singularity refers to a location where the gravitational field is infinite - "a point in spacetime in which gravitational forces cause matter to have an infinite density and zero volume." No idea how helpful that is.

In the comics, the gems correspond to a particular capability. The Power Gem can increases strength and ability of the bearer. Which makes it sound like the Aether but Director James Gunn said on Twitter that the Orb is the supposed to be the equivalent of the comic verse's Power Stone.

The Reality Gem is supposed to have similar effects on a grander scale to the cosmic cube which the Tesseract is likely modeled after - cos it's a cube? So I suppose the Tesserect is supposed to be the Reality gem.

Aether may or may not be comparable to the Soul Gem which can steal the souls of living being. Although there is a Dr. Strange movie coming up and he was the guardian of the soul gem in the comics so the soul gem could be another infinity stone yet to be revealed.

Besides the Power and the Reality gem, there are the Time, Space, Mind and Soul gems - so the Aether and the other three stones may be loosely based off of their capabilities.

You can go here to read more in depth on the topic: http://marvel.wikia.com/Infinity_Gems

Comment: i was under them impression the claims were Space, Reality, and Power for the Tessaract (multidimensional object), Aether (hypothetical building block of reality), and Orb respectively.  I thought all of these were confirmed but don't have the source.

Comment: Well nope. As of 4/12/17, we now know that Tesseract = Space Stone. Aether = Reality Stone. Orb = Power Stone. Sceptor = Mind Stone. Eye of Agomotto = Time Stone. Only thing left is Soul Stone, presumeably to be found in Ragnarok.