# Can anyone call upon Heimdall?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, thor-marvel

Can anyone, regardless of whether they're Asgardian, or not, call upon him? Or is this solely a treat of the Asgardians?

Is Heimdall always listening to everyone, everywhere?

**Is there any canon evidence showing anyone else (for example Jane Foster) able to call upon him and getting an answer back?**

Comment: Anyone can call upon anyone.  The problem is getting the other guy to answer.

Comment: Do you have any evidence of that? Has there ever been a mortal calling upon him and getting an answer?

Comment: It seemed to me from watching the first Thor film, and knowing the comics and Nordic mythos That anyone can call upon Heimdall to create the Bifrost Bridge for them, but Heimdall makes the decision as to whether it's opened or not, subject only to Odin's whims and possibly not even then. His role is after all, as the Guardian of the gate of Asgard.

Comment: planning to go to Asgard are we ???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anyone can call upon Heimdall with no problem at all - we know from both *Thor* and *Thor: The Dark World* that he can see everything in each of the nine realms at all time, and as such will obviously notice you calling on him.

What we don't know, however, is how he reacts to being called upon apart from in a few very specific circumstances. We have seen in both *Thor: The Dark World* and *Avengers: Age of Ultron* that he will happily open the Bifrost for Thor when he calls, but we also see in *Thor* that he is unwilling to open the Bifrost if it will endanger Asgard (we see this when Thor, Loki, Lady Sif and the Warriors Three unsuccessfully call on him to open the Bifrost when they attack Jotunheim).

I don't think we've seen an example of a non-Asgardian calling on Heimdall to open the Bifrost in the Marvel Cinematic Universe so far, but I see no reason that he would given his status of Sentry Guardian of Asgard. After all, he wouldn't even answer Thor, the Prince of Asgard and a personal friend, after he had been banished from Asgard and stripped of his powers by Odin in *Thor*.

But overall, no - In the Marvel Cinematic Universe, there is no evidence showing any non-Asgardian being able to successfully call on Heimdall.

Comment: “we know from both Thor and Thor: The Dark World that he can see everything in each of the nine realms at all time” — is that right? I feel like we had a question about this before, and if he could literally see everything everywhere all the time, that would be quite an advantage for Thor and his buddies.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I can't add a quote right now, but I'm fairly certain he is talking to Thor at the end of *Thor* and tells him how Jane Foster is doing after Thor left Earth. I also believe that a similar conversation about Heimdall's vision takes place in *Thor: The Dark World*, but I may be mistaken - these are the Marvel Studios films I have seen the least.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I was just about to say that. Thor and co. should really have an incredible advantage if they were to know what was happening at all times everywhere. Isn't the Helicarrier ambushed by evil Hawkeye in the Avengers? Where was Heimdall's phonecall? Not even a text message...

Comment: @Daft Obviously, Heimdall had used up all his texts and minutes that month.

Comment: @DrRDizzle You're probably right, Asgardian cell phone plans are notoriously crappy.

Comment: Heimdall the ultimate peeping Tom

Comment: @Petersaber Like a large, sword wielding, intimidating, and giftless Santa Claus.

Comment: @DrRDizzle I am now imaging Heimdall somewhere, watching Jane Foster for Thor, silently going "hoe hoe hoe"...

Comment: @PaulD.Waite You may be thinking of [Can’t Heimdall see all the Infinity Stones? (And other concerns.)](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/77059/5184)

Comment: He also answered the call of Sif in AoS, but that doesn't change the answer at all since she's Asgardian.

Comment: @phantom42: that’s the one!

Comment: @PaulD.Waite I believe the idea is that Heimdall can see everywhere in the universe *if he looks*; if he doesn't know where the Infinity Stones are he might not think/know to look there.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield In *Thor: The Dark World*, he is unable to locate Jane Foster when she travels to the place where the Aether is kept, so we know that there are at least some places he cannot see.